# How do I configure Pidgin to allow video chat with people using WLMessenger?

Tags: pidgin

I have a Windows Live ID and I use it to talk with my friends, who use Windows Live Messenger 2009 or 2011. I've adopted Pidgin as my main conversation client because it is universal and it is cross-platform.

However I still can't have video conversations with my contacts, the options are all grey and I can't configure anything.

How do I configure pidgin to be able to make video and audio conversations with Windows Live Messenger users? Is there any missing plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, for the simple reason that **it's not correctly implemented** for now.

---

From Pidgin's [FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#VoiceandVideoMicrophoneandWebcamSupport):

> **Does Pidgin support voice or video?**
>  Yes, Pidgin does support voice and video, but this is limited to Unix-like platforms and the
>   XMPP protocol (including GoogleTalk).

More documentation can be found [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/vv) with current progress on video chat support in Pidgin.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of this. That means I have to find an alternative compatible with WLM, because unfortunately I can't convice all of my friends to drop Microsoft chat client. It's a shame because I love pidgin.

Comment: Have you tried [this Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocaebkdojpikfmhmnekiflipcicedobi/reviews?hl=en-US)?

Comment: No I haven't, I will try it too. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can try third-party plugin from:

http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins

msn-xmpp - but i think it will not work(although You should try)